# What are mirrors of mathoverflow?

Tags: discussion, mirror-sites

I am looking for mirrors of mathoverflow.

Searching for questions so far found:

http://lfhck.com/site/mathoverflow/1

http://mathdiscussions.aircraftdata.net/

http://hwnvoc.youdegreeearn.com/questions

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you’re asking this?  To shame malign mirrors who are trying to make money of our content?  To compile benign mirrors who will serve as an archive if StackExchange turns evil or goes bust?  Pure curiosity?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine The reasons in no particular order: pure curiosity, options in case official MO is down and to see the technical solutions for running a mirror. Since the license allows profiting, don't try to shame anyone (though don't like ads).

Comment: @joro: it is not because something is allowed that it is necessarily not shameful.

Comment: @Joël I neither criticize nor promote the mirrors in the question.

Comment: I have found helptouser.com , which reposts the content of this site (and math.SE, I think?) without attribution.  I don't know if it reposts the answers, though. (sidebar: I believe this site should be against our copyright, whatever we have, but I don't know if this is the case)

Comment: @RichardRast According a post of moderator here, in such cases you should inform the moderators via email for potential violation. If you don' like this, raise the possible issue on meta.

Comment: I did not know about that post, thank you.