# MO-clones on other sites

Tags: discussion, copyright, mirror-sites

I don't know how to find the earlier discussions of the problem, that unrelated sites seem to hold copies of MO (and/or of other SE sites) [I searched meta.mo with keywords "clone", "copy" "piracy"... but those keywords didn't help] but I think I remember a remark anywhere that such cases should be reported.
When I tried the google search for "zeta isogone" (to see how google positions its findings - inspired by the other discussion on meta) I find

http://newtips.co/mathoverflow/questions/221202/how-to-formalize-the-loci-of-equal-arg-zetas-isogones-in-the-near-of.html
(I removed some google-specific content in that link, I hope it works anyway)

*Ah, and I don't find a good tag for tagging this correctly, sorry, perhaps someone might help here*

Comment: "Scraper" might be the search term you want.

Comment: The [license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) allows to create and distribute copies of MathOverflow content, but it must be properly [attributed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). On the site you refer to, as far as I see, authors of posts are not mentioned.

Comment: A related questions [listing some mirror sites](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1418/what-are-mirrors-of-mathoverflow).

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed, it might, but trying it,  nothing much of relevance turns up on meta.MO when searching for this. However on MSE one finds something http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do

Comment: I added the tag copyright, and created the tag mirror-sites.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a detailed discussion of how to proceed on Meta Stack Exchange:
[A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

This more-or-less applies to MO, too, as MO uses the very same license.
See for example [Who owns my MathOverflow posts?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/950/who-owns-my-mathoverflow-posts) for information on the license.

As a general point note that as explained in a comment by Stefan Kohl and also on the linked post, it is not always a problem if a site reproduces content, even sizable parts of it. But, there are rules to follow.

In brief steps to take could be:

- Convince yourself if the rules even are/seem to be violated.
- If feasible and in minor cases, say the content of a single post, and where it might just be an oversight, signal the problem to the entity reproducing the content in violation of the attribution rules.
- If the preceding point is not feasible or does not have the desired effect report the problem. See [an other answer](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2591/) for the recommended way to do this.

Comment: Thanks quid for this answer (and for the previous links)

Comment: You are welcome. I think it is good this is documented somewhere, so thanks for the question.

Answer (score 14):

Since the content of MO is distributed under the [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (CC BY-SA 3.0) license, many such sites are perfectly within their rights to redistribute MO content. However, they must respect the terms of the license and the [attribution requirement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). Sites that redistribute MO content without proper attribution should be [reported here](https://mathoverflow.net/contact).